Getting a syntax error in python on VS code but not replit
Im trying a very basic recursion question but while running it on VS code, its throwing all kinds of syntax errors but it works perfectly fine on replit, any reason why this is happening? I think the code i correct but why does VS code throw the errors?
The code on VS:(https://i.sstatic.net/I94NVrWk.png)

What was the point of posting an image of your code?  Do you really expect people to have to retype it all if they want to test the code for themselves?  The really useful thing you could have posted would have been these "all kinds of syntax errors" - without that, I can't even guess at what the problem is.

Your traceback shows "line 1" while actually on line 8. So, somehow you ran the code line by line wondering that names from the other lines are missing.

@jasonharper No need to be angry about it. OP - please check out Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors? and [edit] your question to use code fences instead. Also read Why should I post complete errors? Why isn't the message itself enough? and the guide for writing an [mre].
